# Swap out views with Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've looked around but have yet to find a great solution the the following problem:

I have a Backbone View tied to an el on the page that is a container element for what I'll call a "sidebar" in the traditional sense (for explanation's sake).  *This sidebar element's inner-html needs to change completely depending on the route*.  However, *the position on the page never changes, and will always fill this container*.

Now, for an initial prototype, I had a 1:1 relationship between this container and the view placed in it (I only coded up one route).  Now however, said view needs to change based on the route as I've mentioned.

Being that these different views have entirely different html markup, response to events, etc... **I had thought that I'd make sense to have a higher level view that'd swap in sub-views**.  Of course, one solution that would ***work*** would be to handle everything in the same view, but the necessary logic would be cumbersome (and pretty damn unwieldy).

**Currently, here's what I'm thinking (and have partially implemented)**:

- Have a top-level view for this page element.
- Depending on the route, swap in the necessary sub-view.

  - These subviews are rendered with dust.js, where the .html template for just this component on the page is lazy-loaded via AJAX, compiled, and cached.  Subsequent renders just consist of calling the cached "compiled" function with a new context.
  - Additionally, I was going to initialize and cache each of the subview Views within the top-level View, such that I'm only instantiating, setting up event handlers, etc.. once.

Then, depending on the route, look up the associated subview View (cached), and swap it in in-place of the current view.

Now, as I've mentioned, I have this mostly coded up and... semi-working.  However, what I'm struggling with is **how to have each of these subviews exist independently and handle the swapping, but keep all of the event handlers and current state to continuing to live whether the component is currently displayed or not**.

***Basically:***

- How to avoid completely destroying  / re-instantiating subviews each time they're required.  Maybe this operation isn't as expensive as I'm thinking it is and I should simply do the latter.
- Being that the top-level View (the "manager", if you will) is tied to the container $el, how to swap in the subviews.

I'm sure there's a simple, elegant solution.  I just haven't found it yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as point 1 is concerned I don't think it is too expensive to let the view be created each time.

For point 2 - I would recommend using Backbone.Marionette https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette. It has the concept of a Layout which lets you define different regions of your app and render/manage them individually.

I would recommend Backbone.Marionette not just for point 2 but for the way in which it allows you to manage interaction is in my opinion much better than standard Backbone.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer!  It ended up being incredibly useful.  Despite the fact that I'd seen and actually followed Backbone Marionette before, I didn't have a solid enough understanding of Backbone or the real problems it was trying to so solve (or boilerplate eliminate) at the time.  This time around, it literally felt creepy because it so accurately addressed the hurdles I was experiencing!  Thanks for making the association between my problem(s) and this incredibly useful solution!

Comment: You're welcome :-) I've been through similar steps so it was clear to see this time around.